# How to access mongodb behind haproxy - message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, haproxy

I'm attempting to connect to mongodb which is behind a haproxy. However i get the following error message when connecting.

```
mongo --host mongo.<redacted>.com:27017
```

> MongoDB shell version v4.2.8 connecting to:
> mongodb://mongo.redacted.com:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> 2020-07-31T08:52:58.942+0100 I  NETWORK  [js] recv(): message msgLen
> 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000
> 2020-07-31T08:52:58.942+0100 I  NETWORK  [js] DBClientConnection
> failed to receive message from mongo..com:27017 -
> ProtocolError: recv(): message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16
> Max: 48000000 2020-07-31T08:52:58.942+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error:
> network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host
> 'mongo.redacted.com:27017'  : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
> @(connect):2:6 2020-07-31T08:52:58.946+0100 F  -        [main]
> exception: connect failed 2020-07-31T08:52:58.946+0100 E  -
> [main] exiting with code 1

**haproxy.cfg**

```
global
  user root
  group root
  log stdout local0 debug

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  balance leastconn
  retries 3
  option http-server-close
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout check 5s
  timeout client 60s
  timeout server 60s
  option forwardfor


listen mongo
  bind *:27017
  mode tcp
  server prod-mongodb-svc prod-mongodb-svc.mongodb:27017
```

Both HAProxy and MongoDB services are deployed in a kubernetes cluster. The HAProxy service is deployed as a load balancer (aws-elb). I have created an A record `mongo.<redacted>.com` which points to this load balancer.

Comment: Your proxy seems to be corrupting data.

Comment: @D.SM What does that mean? How is that happening?

Comment: It means the data your proxy is sending is violating the MongoDB wire protocol. Why it does that I don't know, my guess is you misconfigured it. Add links to documentation you followed to set everything up.

Comment: `  mode http` in particular looks suspicious.

Comment: Im setting mode tcp in listen mongo

Comment: Can you share the HAProxy logs corresponding to the mongodb request ?